# Help on implementing DataList's RepeatColumns in GridView needed!

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

By default there is no `RepeatColumns` property in the `GridView` control to let us add an additional cells into the rows, like it is done in the `DataList`.
I could use the `DataList`, but it has no pager support that I really need. So I'm looking for the method to add such a feature to the `GridView`. So now I come up with:

```
protected void GvwCollection_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= GvwCollection.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            x = i % 4;
            if (i != 0 && x != 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    GvwCollection.Rows[y].Cells.Add(GvwCollection.Rows[i].Cells[0]);
                }
                catch { }
            }
            else { y = i; }
        }
    }
```

But it is not working as it was meant to be.
Finally, I need to get something like this (4 cells in row):

```
1 | 2  | 3  | 4
5 | 6  | 7  | 8
9 | 10 | 11 | 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use ListView - it can tile as per your requirements. See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/09/24/using-the-listview-control-in-tiled-mode.aspx) and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616112920/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010208-1.aspx).

BTW, you can also do paging with DataList without using DataPager control - see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/07/434787.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
protected void dgEmp_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dgEmp.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        if (i%4 ==0 && i!=0)
        {
            y++;
       }
        dgEmp.Rows[y].Cells.Add(dgEmp.Rows[i].Cells[0]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Table server control and build all the rows/columns programatically.  That is going to be the easiest approach, as you then have full control over the UI.  The gridview isn't really meant for this.

HTH.